# Not able to access graphql api for magento (with XAMPP) on localhost

Tags: graphql

Am new to Magento. Am using magento 2.3.1 with XAMPP v3.2.3.

Does the XAMPP exposes the graphql api by default on localhost or I need to setup separate server for it like Apollo? I'm trying to set endpoints with localhost (in chromiql as well as in postman) but has not been successful. The idea is to query the data using graphql and later on integrate with AEM.

I can see there are many graph-ql schema already present in Magento modules. I have set the mode to developer as well.